# Maximum values of SonarQube DB Cleaner's Keys/Constants

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

SonarQube is automatically deleting measurement data for files for the  older snapshots. When a new snapshot is taken, the old one get deleted. I can see measurement data for files only for the latest snapshot. My db cleaner settings are as as below.

[image: Database Cleaner Settings]

What are the maximum allowed values for the keys/constants? Am I using too high value for the keys that they somehow overflow and does not work? What should I do if I do not want SonarQube to auto delete any measurement data for older snapshots?

I am using SonarQube version: 6.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Automatic clean-up of old analysis cannot be disabled. Still setting high values like 100'000 (days) means that analysis are kept during 274 years. Maybe the ability to disable auto-cleaning will be implemented during this period.

Comment: My bad!!! How do I solve this issue now. 

I at least now know that nothing is wrong with my settings. Still it would be nice to know the max values of the keys. 

Thanks a lot Simon for your response.